# using core audio and wave audio together on windows

Tags: audio, visual-c++, core-audio, audio-streaming, audio-capture

I am planning to use c++ core Audio API's to perform various audio related operations in my application like detecting device change, detecting volume levels etc. But there is also an Audio capture code in my solution that uses old Wave API's (waveInxxx) which I don't want to touch right now.
Can I use core Audio API's safely and can these (core and wave) co exist together given that both these would operate on same audio end point? Will this lead to crash or hang in my application ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the old wave APIs safely. They are now implemented in terms of Core Audio APIs.

This MSDN page describes how the old APIs are implemented in terms of Core Audio:

[Interoperability with Legacy Audio APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371428(v=vs.85).aspx)

And this page has a nice diagram showing how things are plugged together.

[User-Mode Audio Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316780(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped